# grep with multiple NOT and AND operators

Tags: bash, grep

I am looking for a multiple grep with NOT and AND conditions. I have a directory with with txt files and some csv files which have the date included in the filename. I want to delete the csv files that do not include today’s date. The directory does include csv files with previous dates. So I am trying the code below in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y")
dir="/var/tmp/"
for f in "$dir"/*; do
   ls -1 | grep -v *$now* | grep *csv* | xargs rm -f
done
```

This is not deleting anything. If I take out the grep *csv* operator then it deletes the text files. Only the CSV files have dates on them, the text files don’t. Please advise.

Comment: `for f in "$dir/"*.csv`? Also it would be better if you didn't use smart quotes/etc. in the post. Or with `extglob` on just `rm -f !("$dir/"*"$now"*.csv);` I think.

Comment: ls -1 | grep -i  *$now* | grep -i  *csv* | xargs rm -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the `find` utility for this:

```
find /var/tmp -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' ! -name "*$now*" -delete
```

If you want to do it with grep,

```
ls -1 /var/tmp/*.csv | grep -v "$now" | xargs rm -f
```

should also work.

EDIT: `-delete` in the `find` command instead of `-exec rm '{}' \;`. Thanks @amphetamachine.

Comment: `find ... -delete` is faster.

Comment: not only faster but much more conservative in the use of system resources, ie. an 'exec' for each file vs an exec for each command buffer full of filenames.

Comment: That could be taken care of with `+` instead of `\;`, but long command lines are a bit icky in their own right. Unless OP has a *lot* of files there, neither is probably critical, but there's no doubt `-delete` is nicer overall.